# Why is AIDL necessary to support multithreading?

Tags: android, multithreading, aidl

Based on this message from the [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) docs there is only one valid usecase for AIDL.

> Using AIDL is necessary only if you allow clients from different applications to access your service for IPC and want to handle multithreading in your service.

What exactly does "handle multithreading" mean in this context? Is this more than simply having a service with multiple running threads?

The docs further state:

> if you want to perform IPC, but do not need to handle multithreading, implement your interface using a Messenger.

Why is a Messenger unacceptable for a service that supports multithreading? Couldn't communication between threads be handled inside the messenger (without the use of shared memory)?

Is the issue here that this code would be significantly more complicated then using a Handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means AIDL calls can be concurrent (e.g. several apps calling the same AIDL interface on same service) because Android handles this for you, but with `Messenger` it is not (but you can do it manually though).

Comment: So its fine to have many clients of the service instantiate messengers and send messages to the service, but these messages won't be processed concurrently?

Comment: No, it's not fine since it might be not thread safe depending on how you implemented it. What I mean is if you use `Messenger`, you have to take care of potential thread safety.

Comment: Hmmm, here though the thread safety would happen after messages have been processed. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) it seems like having many threads send messages through a messenger is fine. (See the note on the left). The biggest difference it seems to be is that AIDL will automatically create a thread pool for you. The level of concurrency management is nearly the same.

Comment: Yes, correct, you need to create threads yourself. I actually have implemented my service supporting multi-threading using Messenger, not AIDL.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html. Messnger uses single thread to queue messages. Hence no need to handle any sync issues. In case of AIDL its the responsibility of the developer.